# Filter begin and end characters from a string

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, filter

I receive the following string every time I open the serial port, this string is for checking which bios version and which firmware version the connected device is running.

String:

```
v03400216000000001FC5H240108206B-RAMBOX=[03]
```

Now the only important charachters for checking the Bios version and Firmware version are the following:

```
03400216
```

Note: `bytearray` is a `byte[]` converted to a `string` and is filled with:

```
v03400216000000001FC5H240108206B-RAMBOX=[03]
```

I tried achieving this using the following code:

```
string versiontext = bytearray.Trim();
bytearray = versiontext.Remove(0, 2);
versiontext = bytearray.Remove(9, bytearray.Length);
bytearray = versiontext;
```

But that didn't work out and resulted in the following exception:

```
Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
```

Should I use a `Regex`, Instead of the `.Remove`?

EDIT:

@lazyberezovsky Helped me out, I just forgot about the `.Substring()`.

I achieved the `string result` with the following code:

```
if (bytearray.Contains("RAMBOX"))
{
       string Versionstring = bytearray.Substring(1, 8);
       bytearray = Versionstring;
}
```

Comment: It depends, will it **always** be 8 characters after the initial `v`?  Or could it vary?

Comment: The input String is always this long, and yes the characters I need are always the characters 1 to 9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about simple substring?

```
var input = "v03400216000000001FC5H240108206B-RAMBOX=[03]";
var version = input.Substring(1, 8);
```

Comment: @Mobstaa I never thought I'd see someone forget about good ol' `Substring()`... until I forgot about it myself :p

Comment: haha I used it in my code like thousand of times, but had a tough weekend and I guess to much on my mind to just forget the Good .Substring, and was all doing it hard, with the .Remove. I will accept your answer, when Stack allows me to:)